# How to stop onclick action in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

When the button is clicked, I want the spiners to appear for 3 seconds and then disappear. I can make it visible but I can't make it invisible again.

```js
function stoploading() {
  document.getElementById('loading').style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-danger d-inline-flex align-items-center" type="button">ATTACK</button>

<div class="col text-white m-5 px-5">
  <div id="loading" class="spinner-border text-primary load_icon" role="status">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: You can set `display` CSS property to `none` to make it invisible and use `block` to make it appear again.

Comment: Why did you turn the code from text in to images? That's far, far worse.

Comment: Also, why do you want to make it spin for three seconds? If you're loading something, then show the spinner when the button is clicked then hide it when the (presumably AJAX) load completes.

Answer (score 0):

So I created a `<button>` and a function `startLoading()`that removes the "Loading..." after 3 seconds.

```html
<button onclick="startLoading()">Click</button>

<script>
    function startLoading() {
        // Make he spinner visible
        document.getElementById('loading').style.visibility = 'visible';

        // Set a timeout to hide the spinner after 3 seconds
        setTimeout(function() {
            stopLoading();
        }, 3000);
    }

    function stopLoading() {
        // Make the spinner invisible
        document.getElementById('loading').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
</script>

<div class="col text-white m-5 px-5">
    <div id="loading" class="spinner-border text-primary load_icon" role="status">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OF your welcome!

Answer (score 0):

you may apply hidden style to loading after 3 second

```html
<button onclick="stoploading()">
    ATTACK
</button>

<script>
    function stoploading() {
        // Make the spinner visible
        document.getElementById('loading').style.visibility = 'visible';

        // Set a timeout to 3 seconds
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById('loading').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }, 3000); 
    }
</script>

<div class="col text-white m-5 px-5">
    <div id="loading" class="spinner-border text-primary load_icon" role="status">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

or you can also use classList.add('visible'); and classList.remove('visible'); to have same effects

Answer (score 0):

Simple and Easy:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="btn btn-danger d-inline-flex align-items-center" onclick="onclickButtonHandler()" type="button">ATTACK</button>

    <div id="loadingElement" class="col text-white m-5 px-5">
    <div id="loading" class="spinner-border text-primary load_icon" role="status">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
    </div>
    </div>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script>
        document.getElementById('loadingElement').style.display = 'none';
        function onclickButtonHandler(){
            document.getElementById('loadingElement').style.display = 'block';
            setTimeout(hideLoading,3000);
        }

        function hideLoading() { 
            document.getElementById('loadingElement').style.display = 'none';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```